# SQSListener with ThreadpoolExecutor

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-cloud, amazon-sqs

In the below example , I am setting the max and core pool size to 1. However no messages are being processed. When I enable debug log , I am able to see the messages being pulled from SQS , but I guess it is not being processed / deleted. However when I increase core and max pool size to 2 , the messages seem to be processed.

**EDIT**

I believe Spring maybe allocating a thread for receiver which reads data off the queue and hence it is unable to allocate a thread to listener which is processing the message. When I increased the corepoolsize to 2 , I saw that messages were being read off the queue. When I added another listener (for dead letter queue) , I encountered the same issue - 2 threads were not sufficient as the messages were not being processed. When I increased the corepoolsize to 3 , it started processing the messages. I assume in this case , 1 thread was allocated to read messages off the queue and 2 listeners were assigned 1 thread each.

```
@Configuration
public class SqsListenerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "aws.configuration")
    public ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration() {
        return new ClientConfiguration();
    }


    @Bean
    @Primary
    public AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider() {

        ProfileCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new ProfileCredentialsProvider("credential");
        try {
            credentialsProvider.getCredentials();
            System.out.println(credentialsProvider.getCredentials().getAWSAccessKeyId());
            System.out.println(credentialsProvider.getCredentials().getAWSSecretKey());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AmazonClientException(
                    "Cannot load the credentials from the credential profiles file. " +
                            "Please make sure that your credentials file is at the correct " +
                            "location (~/.aws/credentials), and is in valid format.",
                    e);
        }
        return credentialsProvider;
    }


    @Bean
    @Primary
    public AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync() {
        return AmazonSQSAsyncClientBuilder.standard().
                withCredentials(awsCredentialsProvider()).
                withClientConfiguration(clientConfiguration()).
                build();
    }


    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "aws.queue")
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainer simpleMessageListenerContainer(AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer simpleMessageListenerContainer = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        simpleMessageListenerContainer.setAmazonSqs(amazonSQSAsync);
        simpleMessageListenerContainer.setMessageHandler(queueMessageHandler());
        simpleMessageListenerContainer.setMaxNumberOfMessages(10);
        simpleMessageListenerContainer.setTaskExecutor(threadPoolTaskExecutor());
        return simpleMessageListenerContainer;
    }


    @Bean
    public QueueMessageHandler queueMessageHandler() {
        QueueMessageHandlerFactory queueMessageHandlerFactory = new QueueMessageHandlerFactory();
        queueMessageHandlerFactory.setAmazonSqs(amazonSQSAsync());
        QueueMessageHandler queueMessageHandler = queueMessageHandlerFactory.createQueueMessageHandler();
        return queueMessageHandler;
    }


    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(1);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(1);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("oaoQueueExecutor");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }


    @Bean
    public QueueMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate(@Autowired AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync) {
        return new QueueMessagingTemplate(amazonSQSAsync);
    }


}
```

**Listener Config**

```
    @SqsListener(value = "${oao.sqs.url}", deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.ON_SUCCESS)
    public void onMessage(String serviceData, @Header("MessageId") String messageId, @Header("ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp") String approximateFirstReceiveTimestamp) {

        System.out.println(" Data = " + serviceData + " MessageId = " + messageId);

        repository.execute(serviceData);
}
```

Comment: Here is the ticket that I had created for this question - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/issues/321

Answer (score 18, accepted):

By setting `corePoolSize` and `maximumPoolSize` the same, you create a `fixed-size thread pool`. A very good explanation of the rules are documented [here](http://www.bigsoft.co.uk/blog/2009/11/27/rules-of-a-threadpoolexecutor-pool-size)

Setting `maxPoolSize` implicitly allows for tasks to get dropped.
However, the default queue capacity is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, which, for practical purposes, is infinity.

Something to watch out for is that `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` uses a `ThreadPoolExecutor` underneath, which has a somewhat unusual approach to queueing, described in [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html):

> If `corePoolSize` or more threads are running, the Executor always prefers queuing a request rather than adding a new thread.

This means that `maxPoolSize` is only relevant when the queue is full, otherwise the number of threads will never grow beyond `corePoolSize`.
As an example, if we submit tasks **that never complete** to the thread pool:

- the first `corePoolSize` submissions will start a new thread each;
- after that, all submissions go to the queue;
- if the queue is finite and its capacity is exhausted, each submission starts a new thread, up to `maxPoolSize`;
- when both the pool and the queue are full, new submissions are rejected.

**Queuing** - Read the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)

Any `BlockingQueue` may be used to transfer and hold submitted tasks. The use of this queue interacts with pool sizing:

- If fewer than corePoolSize threads are running, the Executor always
  prefers adding a new thread rather than queuing.
- If corePoolSize or    more threads are running, the Executor always
  prefers queuing a    request rather than adding a new thread.
- If a request cannot be    queued, a new thread is created unless
  this would exceed maximumPoolSize, in which case, the task will
  be    rejected.

> `Unbounded queues`. Using an unbounded queue (for example a
>   `LinkedBlockingQueue` without a predefined capacity) will cause new
>   tasks to be queued in cases where all corePoolSize threads are busy.
>   Thus, no more than `corePoolSize` threads will ever be created. (And the
>   value of the `maximumPoolSize` therefore doesn't have any effect.)

1. If the number of threads is less than the `corePoolSize`, create a new
   Thread to run a new task.
2. If the number of threads is equal (or greater than) the
   `corePoolSize`, put the task into the queue.
3. If the queue is full, and the number of threads is less than the
   `maxPoolSize`, create a new thread to run tasks in.
4. If the queue is full, and the number of threads is greater than or
   equal to `maxPoolSize`, reject the task.

Comment: Thanks @Vikram Palakurthi. In my example , I haven't set the queue capacity. So I believe it is infinity. Hence the maxpoolsize I assume is not relevant. I tried pushing about 10 messages to the SQS FIFO queue. Since corepoolsize is set to 1 , I was assuming that the consumer will processes the messages one by one. But the consumer isn't fetching the messages. However when I set it to 2 , the messages are being read. Is one thread always dedicated to polling messages and hence if I set the queue size to 2 , the second messages is doing the processing?

Comment: No not for polling but I guess in your case executor.setCorePoolSize(1);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(1); the 4th rule is being applied and the task is being rejected. If you see the order of the rules, I somewhat guess the executor detects the threads are greater than maxPoolSize which is 1 and rejecting the tasks, which explains why the processing works when you increase it to 2.

Comment: By setting corePoolSize and maximumPoolSize the same, you created a fixed-size thread pool, leaving it no way to dynamically allocation growing threads. Try removing this part executor.setMaxPoolSize(1); and see how it goes.

Comment: I guess the maxpoolsize kicks in only if the queue capacity is reached. This is even stated in your answer -"This means that maxPoolSize is only relevant when the queue is full".In my case , I am just posting 4-5 messages to queue to test.  I also tried increasing the maxpoolsize to 1. But there is no effect due to this configuration. Only if I increase core pool size to greater than 1 , it works.

Comment: Correct, in your case corePoolSize is 1, since you have about 4-5 messages, the maxPoolSize will kick in. And since you gave both corePoolSize and maxPoolSize as 1 which caused the problem. You mentioned you tried increasing maxPoolSize to 1, which will not fix your problem, trying increasing it to anything greater than 1, like 2-5.

Comment: Sorry Vikram , I increased it to 10. It was a typo

Comment: I think max poolsize will kick in only when queue capacity is hit. In this case queue capacity is unlimited , so I guess max poolsize wouldn’t take effect